# rsyncd.conf include local conf?

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

We have a default /etc/rsyncd.conf being synced on all our servers, defining the default backup modules we use.
For some server I need to add some custom modules in there, without having them defined everywhere.

Is there a way to include another config file from /etc/rsyncd.conf ? Maybe a /etc/rsyncd.local for example ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `&include` and `&merge` to include or merge additional config. For more details see the CONFIG DIRECTIVES in the manpage of rsyncd.conf.